# Silverlight / Blend - How to create FontSize dependency property with dropdown list

Tags: silverlight, drop-down-menu, dependency-properties, font-size, blend

In my custom behavior I have created the following dependency property:

```
public double FontSize
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "FontSize",
        typeof (double),
        typeof (CustomBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata(11, null));
```

1. How to bind value, 'couse In Blend binding button is disabled.
2. How to show dropdown list of standart font sizes like for Textblock in Text category

Comment: This is in a class that is derived from `System.Windows.Interactivity.Behaviour` ?

Comment: Did you solved this issue in the meantime?
We have exactly the same requirement. Many thanks in advance, Michael

Comment: No, still can't find an answer(((

Comment: Which version of Silverlight are you guys using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps or if you already found the answer but I here it goes for ...

**Part 2 of your question:**

You first declare an enum of items:

```
public enum DDItems
{
    Default = 0,
    Item1 = 1,
    Item2 = 2,
    Item3 = 3,
    Item4 = 4,
    Item5 = 5
}
```

And then you have the dependency property like this:

```
    public DDItems TextSearchModeABC
    {
        get
        {
            return (DDItems)GetValue(MyItemProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyItemProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyItemProperty", typeof(DDItems), typeof(MyControlType), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Hope this helps.